# Internet Explorer not getting the most updated javascript files

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-11

Whenever we deploy code updates on our Server, some of our end-users start to encounter issues with our website. Until we notice during a remote session that the latest javascript version we deployed is not reflecting correctly in their Internet Explorer (the only browser supported so far). Hence, we asked them to clear temporary files. Note that we've already set up their browsers with "Every time I visit the webpage" to make sure that their browser temp files got updated but not always the case.

Mostly, this happens to our users using Windows 10 with IE 11 version.

Is there a way to avoid this issue every time we make deployments?
Our website was built with MVC, Jquery, and WCF.

**UPDATE:**

the javascript url looks like this:

```
https://mywebsite.com/MyWeb/Scripts/Web-Scripts.js?release=1LVSdi77VO6loK2pZ2X+Vjs1tXYKuwtvnoU4DFggLdM= 

Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Length: 348182 Content-Type: application/x-javascript Date: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 06:23:55 GMT ETag: "c76398d68729d41:0" Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Aug 2018 11:07:29 GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

scripts are rendered through this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.js?release=@Request.Cookies["Release-Date"].Value"></script>
```

We only deploy all the affected files to our server during deployment.
Also, when we remote our users, we see the outdated file by decrypting the encrypted string located in the javascript URL. We resolve it by clearing the temporary files in their IEs.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show us an example of the url for the JS file, and the response headers (particularly the caching headers) when downloading that file? _Getting the caching headers is generally easiest from Developer Tools in Chrome, Network tab).

Comment: Check out bundling and minification. The resulting script bundle, if setup correctly, will append an id as a querystring element. This makes the browser believe it is a unique file and will update the cached version. Browser will aggressively cache  resources, and JavaScript files are both the most beneficial from caching and most dangerous since they implement functionality.

Comment: @mjwills it looks like this:
https://MyWebsite.com/MyWeb/Scripts/Web-Scripts.js?release=1LVSdi77VO6loK2pZ2X+Vjs1tXYKuwtvnoU4DFggLdM= 

Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 348182
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Date: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 06:23:55 GMT
ETag: "c76398d68729d41:0"
Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Aug 2018 11:07:29 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick we are actually adding an encrypted string to the javascript file to let the browser know that it has been updated.
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.js?release=@Request.Cookies["Release-Date"].Value"></script>

Comment: `we are actually adding an encrypted string to the javascript file to let the browser know` And after the deployment, the javascript URL changes but the browser is caching the **old** content under the **new** url?

Comment: Talk us through how you handle deployments. Do you deploy to half of your web servers, for example, and then the other half? Something else?

Comment: @carl Are you sure the cookie is getting updated correctly? If you use bundling and minification it does all this for you at deployment. Also, referencing a cookie on the thing that is requesting the URL seems a bit odd since you are further relinquishing control to the browser to determine if the file is new. It could be something as simple as instead of updating the Release-Date query in IE you've added a new one or it isn't actually set as expected.

Comment: please see my answers on the updated question section.

Answer (score 1):

Our company used to have this problem, until I implemented the following low-tec solution.

It works like this:

1. the first time the application loads, create a hash of the contents of the javascript file;
2. store the hash in cache (so that we don't have to continually hash out the contents when the page is served again);
3. return the hash in the querystring of the js file;

This forces the browser to reload the javascript (i.e. request the file again to the backend) whenever the hash changes, which will be whenever the content of the file changes...

You will need to put this in the header of your markup file...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<%=ResolveStaticUrl("Web-Scripts.js", true)%>"></script>
```

And put this in your codebehind file...

```
    private static object syncLock = new object();
    private static Dictionary<String, object[]> lstCachedHashes = new Dictionary<String, object[]>();
    public static String ResolveStaticUrl(String staticFile, Boolean hashObject)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(staticFile))
            return "";

        String strFile = "";
        String strQuery = "";

        String strVirtualPath = "";
        String strPhysicalPath = "";

        int index = staticFile.IndexOf("?", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (index == -1)
        {
            strFile = staticFile;
            strQuery = "";
        }
        else
        {
            strFile = staticFile.Substring(0, index);
            strQuery = staticFile.Substring(index + 1);
        }

        strVirtualPath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(strFile);
        String strFileHash = "";
        if (hashObject)
        {
            strPhysicalPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(strFile);

            DateTime dteFileDate = DateTime.MinValue;
            if (lstCachedHashes.ContainsKey(strVirtualPath))
            {
                object[] arr = lstCachedHashes[strVirtualPath];

                // get from cache
                dteFileDate = Convert.ToDateTime(arr[0], GenericFunctions.GetDefaultLocale());
                strFileHash = Convert.ToString(arr[1], GenericFunctions.GetDefaultLocale());
            }
            else
            {
                // only allow one thread at a time
                lock (syncLock)
                {
                    if (lstCachedHashes.ContainsKey(strVirtualPath))
                    {
                        object[] arr = lstCachedHashes[strVirtualPath];

                        // get from cache
                        dteFileDate = Convert.ToDateTime(arr[0], GenericFunctions.GetDefaultLocale());
                        strFileHash = Convert.ToString(arr[1], GenericFunctions.GetDefaultLocale());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(strPhysicalPath);
                        if (fileInfo.Exists)
                        {
                            dteFileDate = fileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc;
                            strFileHash = CacheControl.GetFileHash(fileInfo);
                            // put in cache
                            lstCachedHashes.Add(strVirtualPath, new object[] { dteFileDate, strFileHash });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // buildo PathAndQuery and return
        UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder();
        builder.Path = strVirtualPath;
        builder.Query = strQuery;
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection q = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strFileHash) == false)
        {
            q.Add("v", strFileHash);
        }
        builder.Query = q.ToString();

        return builder.Uri.PathAndQuery;
    }

    public static String GetFileHash(System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        if ((fileInfo == null) || !fileInfo.Exists)
            return "";

        using (System.IO.FileStream stream = fileInfo.OpenRead())
        {
            using (System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed sha = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed())
            {
                byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
                return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", String.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks good but based on your experience are there any performance issues doing this approach?

Comment: The code has been on production for two years with no problems... You can read more [here](https://tomanistor.com/blog/cache-bust-that-asset/), for other ways on how to break out of the cache of the browser...

Comment: great. I'll give it a try. Thanks for helping out.